# Magento Check the ID of the client if he already bought the product

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I have a product that can only be purchased once only for each customer ..
If I put in the admin, only one item in the shopping cart, Elee can buy one at a time, and so buy more than one time.
How do I check if the "ID" of the customer has already bought, so if they bought the message that he has already purchased this product.?
I think you have to do the buy button

Answer (score 2):

Best thing you could do is write your own observer that is called before/after the add_to_cart event. (Read more about that [here](http://mydons.com/simple-example-using-magento-event-observer/))

Inside that observer file it's best that you get all the previous orders of that particular customer:

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$customer_orders = $orderCollection->getSelect()->where('e.customer_id =CUSTOMER_ID_GOES_HERE');
```

Foreach order of this customer you iterate over all the orderded items, and if one of them matches the product:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
$items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
{
    if($item->getProductId() == ordered_product_id_goes_here){
       //Show output message here that customer can only buy this once
    }
    break;
}
```

Good luck ;)

Comment: I guess it is better to create table customer->product, add new row to it in after order placed observer and check in before order placed observer whether current customer has already bought this product. It is better that look each time through all orders.

Comment: Hi, you wouldn't have to look through ALL orders, just all orders of that customer which shouldn't be a big amount in most cases.